# Animation going put effect on another animation in SwiftUI-macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 deferent and separate Animation in my code for SwiftUI-macOS, I tried this down code, but the animation about `opacity` slow down the animation about `value` for some reason, that effect is not what I want or need! I want the animation about opacity take it place while it works smoothly with animation about `value`. What could be the issue? I need to refactor my code as they are to solve the animation issue. **Xcode: Version 13.2.1 (13C100)**

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var value: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

            Group {
                if value { Color.green.frame(height: 50).transition(AnyTransition.slide) }
            }
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.0), value: value)

            HStack {
                
                ButtonView(color: .red, action: { value.toggle() })
                
                ButtonView(color: .blue, action: { value.toggle() })
                
            }
 
        }

    }
}


struct ButtonView: View {
    
    let color: Color
    let action: () -> Void
    @State private var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        color
            .frame(height: 50)
            .opacity(opacity)
            .onTapGesture {

                if opacity == 1.0 { opacity = 0.2 }
                else { opacity = 1.0 }
                
                action()
                
            }
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5.0), value: opacity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Group` is not real container, actually, it is better to use instead a `V/HStack` with preserved space, like

[image: demo]

```
VStack {
    if value { Color.green.transition(AnyTransition.slide) }
}
.frame(height: 50)   // << here !1
.animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.0), value: value)
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use VStack before asking the question, it did not solved the problem! I cannot change the frame modifier position in code in my code, but I can change Group to VStack or other thing. Also Even if I want use your answer, it has also same issue in question, try run your answer again, it is not what I want. The blue and red buttons should goes up and takes all place, in your code the empty space stay after green goes away.